# Remove button if table is empty

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the start upload button until files are added to the queue, so far I have this code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(CheckTables, 100);
function CheckTables() {
  $("table").each(function (index) {
    $(this).find('tbody:not(:empty)').parent().show();
    $(this).find('tbody:empty').parent().hide();
  });
}
</script>
```

With this code tbody is hidden until files are added but my start upload button, #form-button, is still displayed. I have tried the following...

```
if($.trim($("tbody:empty")
$("#form-button").hide();
```

Hope someone can help with this.

HTML:

```
<button id="form-button" style="margin-bottom:40px" type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
<div id="fileListingWrapper" class="fileListingWrapper hidden">
  <div class="fileSection">
    <table id="upload-table" style="border:1px solid #007FFF;display:none;margin-bottom:10px;border-radius:2px;-moz-border-radius:2px;-webkit-border-radius:2px" id="files" class="files" width="100%"><tbody></tbody></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you have `.parent()` after the `tbody` selection? That would seem to bring you right back to the table. And I have no idea what `if($.trim($("tbody:empty")
$("#form-button").hide();` is supposed to do. And why are you running the code every 100ms? And where's your HTML?

Comment: Without .parent() it does not function correctly, as for the code I tried, I found that browsing here and decided to try it to no avail, its running every 100ms as when a file is added to the queue it is added to tbody, and I need to check when to display the table. And give me a minute and I will add the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have a bit of a syntactical error in the code to hide your submit button (missing multiple parentheses at the end of your if condition). Anyways, here are two approaches you could use for selectively hiding the submit button:

```
if (($("tbody").is(":empty")))
    $("#form-button").hide();
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmjPz/1/) demonstrating the code in use. Try adding stuff (well, valid stuff, like a `<tr>`) inside the `<tbody>`, and the submit button should reappear.

If whitespace is a concern, and you want to ignore it as well, consider using this instead:

```
if (($.trim($("tbody").html()) == ""))
    $("#form-button").hide();
```

Here too, is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmjPz/2/) to show you the code working.

Regardless of which way you take this approach, if you want the button to show again if there is content in the `<tbody>`, make sure you add the code to do so:

```
else
    $("#form-button").show();
```

Hope this helps! If you have any questions, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you, the button is now hidden but when a file is added it does not display, would a setInterval fix this?

Comment: If you're not repeating this check, then yes, you'd need a setInterval - but regardless, you'd also have to add a bit more code in an else statement to show the button again. I'll edit my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

This works ([**demo**](http://codepen.io/ryanw/pen/inICs/))

```
if($("table tbody").html() == "")
{
  $("#form-button").hide();
}
```